# How to design the xml layout of given image in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I need to create an image holder as per the picture given below. Also I need to design the arrow point out the left side.

Any ideas would be appreciable.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create the shape you need in white, and save it as a transaparent PNG-24.  Then overlay it on top of your image.

It will appear exactly as you describe.

In other words, don't overthink modifying the image.  You can create the effect with an extra layer.

Comment: Thanks durbnpoisn. Let me check this idea an let u know